Parameters in Android Studio not inserted autommatically
I recently shifted to android Koala 2024.1.1, after which the default parameters of any function/(Composable or non-composable) is not been inserted automatically as we select a function from suggestion, but it used to happen before updating,   .Also, if  function doesn't have any default parameter, its ()circular brackets are not been inserted, is there any option to enable it ?
before updating-
NavHost(navController = , startDestination = )
after -
NavHost()
Thanks in advance
I tried surfing the internet to find if there any option exists to solve this problem, but failed.
